# BigQuery Regex_Replace first instance of duplicated substring

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I know there are a lot of questions about lazy regex matching, but none of the solutions I've seen have worked. Here's the issue:

Some addresses in my BigQuery results look like this:

```
www.example.comwww.example.com/path/to/page
apply.example.comapply.example.com/eapp/
```

I want to strip off the duplicated part to get

```
www.example.com/path/to/page
apply.example.com/eapp/
```

I've tried using `REGEX_REPLACE()` like this:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(raw.query.tidy_Landing, r'(.*?)\.com','') AS Landing_Page
```

But that still finds both matches and so returns

```
/path/to/page
/eapp/
```

What's wrong with my regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH t AS (
  SELECT 'www.example.comwww.example.com/path/to/page' str UNION ALL
  SELECT 'apply.example.comapply.example.com/eapp/'
)
SELECT str, REGEXP_REPLACE(str, r'^(.*?\.com)', '') fix
FROM t
```

output is

```sql
str                                             fix  
www.example.comwww.example.com/path/to/page     www.example.com/path/to/page  
apply.example.comapply.example.com/eapp/        apply.example.com/eapp/
```

Comment: Ah, I see. The ^ ensures that it's looking form the beginning of the string and stops after a first match. Otherwise it will keep returning matches even though it's lazy and they're distinct.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to see if it's possible to do this without a regex, although it ends up being a bit verbose :) This answer assumes that the address is always duplicated and ends with `.com`. Assuming that's the case, it should be possible to use `SPLIT` to extract the parts that you are interested in:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(
    SPLIT(text, '.com')[OFFSET(0)],
    '.com',
    SPLIT(text, '.com')[OFFSET(2)]
  ) AS Landing_Page
FROM (
  SELECT 'www.example.comwww.example.com/path/to/page' AS text UNION ALL
  SELECT 'apply.example.comapply.example.com/eapp/'
);
```

If you want the query to be tolerant of non-duplicated addresses, you can make a slight modification:

```
SELECT
  (
    SELECT 
      CONCAT(
        parts[OFFSET(0)],
        '.com',
        parts[OFFSET(ARRAY_LENGTH(parts) - 1)]
      )
    FROM (SELECT SPLIT(text, '.com') AS parts)
  ) AS Landing_Page
FROM (
  SELECT 'www.example.comwww.example.com/path/to/page' AS text UNION ALL
  SELECT 'apply.example.comapply.example.com/eapp/' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'www.example.com/path/to/page'
);
```

Going one step further, you can extract the logic into a UDF:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION GetLandingPage(text STRING) AS (
  (
    SELECT 
      CONCAT(
        parts[OFFSET(0)],
        '.com',
        parts[OFFSET(ARRAY_LENGTH(parts) - 1)]
       )
    FROM (SELECT SPLIT(text, '.com') AS parts)
  )
);

SELECT
  GetLandingPage(text) AS Landing_Page
FROM (
  SELECT 'www.example.comwww.example.com/path/to/page' AS text UNION ALL
  SELECT 'apply.example.comapply.example.com/eapp/' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'www.example.com/path/to/page'
);
```

Comment: This is very cool; always up for a UDF solution. Definitely going to tuck this away for more experimentation, thanks!